# c++: Sorted array AKA trying to fix the Selection Sort

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

So i Tried to do this Selection Sort method that read your array and display it from great to least you know

"
these are the unsorted array
29315

these are the sorted array
95321
"

The problem is when i ask the user "to enter how big the array will be" If I type in 6, I only get to enter 5 number only not six, like the example above. What is the issue that Im facing in my function or For loop that prevents me from entering a 6th number

PS: im trying to picture the code to make a dynamic array then a sorted. How would I do that? As you can see below I have the user enter there own array but the limit is n AKA 1000. How can I fix that issue as well please. thank you

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void SelectionSort(int *a, int k);

int main()
{
    int j = 0;
    int n = 1000; //limit of array
    int k = 0; //number of array enters


    cout << "please enter length of array" << endl;
    cin >> k;

    int *a = new int[n];
    //int a[k];

    for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++)
    {
        cout << "please enter the number in the array please" << endl;
        cin >> j;
        a[i] = j;

    }
    cout << "these are the unsorted array" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < k -1; i++){
        cout << a[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    SelectionSort(a, k);

    cout << "these are the sorted array" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < k -1; i++){
        cout << a[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
//function
void SelectionSort(int *a, int k){
    for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++){
        int maxIndex = i;
        for (int j = (i + 1); j < k; j++)
        {
            if (a[j] > a[maxIndex])
            {
                maxIndex = j;
            }
        }

        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[maxIndex];
        a[maxIndex] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great opportunity for you to learn how to use your debugger, so you can step through your code, one line at a time, examine the values of all variables, and determine why your code is doing what you told it to do, instead of what you want it to do. Good luck!

Comment: `k - 1` instead of `k`... so you got `5` instead of expected `6`...

Comment: Why do you do `new int[n]` instead of `new int[k]`?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is when i ask the user "to enter how big the array will be" If I type in 6, I only get to enter 5 number only not six

```
 for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++)
```

Let's say you enter 6 here, this loop will run from 0 to 4 i.e. FIVE times. Hence you are able to enter only FIVE numbers

You can modify this loop like this below:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
```

> PS: im trying to picture the code to make a dynamic array then a sorted. How would I do that? As you can see below I have the user enter their own array but the limit is n AKA 1000. How can I fix that issue as well please. thank you

Your requirement is not clear. Please re-state your question. As mentioned in the comments, I do not see any need for `n`. You can ask the user to input the number of elements required for the array i.e. `k` and then you can dynamically allocate space for so many integers like this:

```
int *a = new int[k];
```